# JSONStringer giving null object in Android 2.1 (update)

Tags: android, json, gson

I am making post call to a web service by sending object in `JSON` format. I am using `GSON` to convert my object to `JSON` and `JSONStringer` to create key-value pair to send to server in a `post` call.

```
    JSONStringer billString = new JSONStringer().object()
                .key("details").value(new JSONObject(json));
   CustomHttpRequest request = new CustomHttpRequest(WebserviceBaseAddress);
        request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        request.AddHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        request.AddParam("entity", billString.toString());
        request.GetRequest(RequestMethod.POST);
```

This line of code works fine in Android 2.2, but 2.1, billString is null. That is why I am getting null exception for (`request.AddParam("entity", billString.toString());`)
Can anybody tell me what is the problem here?
Or is there any way to make key-value pair to make `post` call in `GSON`, so that `JSONStringer` can be removed?

Thanks
Ashwani

Comment: Are you able to post a more complete code example?  What does "it is giving null" mean?  Is the final call to the value method returning a null reference?  Are you getting a NullPointerException from something in that line of code?  What's the value of the json input?

Comment: Here billString is null in Android 2.1, but in Android 2.2 it is an Json string with details as key and a json object as value.

Comment: Are you able to also answer the other questions I asked?

Comment: Hello Bruce, I have updated the post. Is this what u were asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
JSONStringer billString = new JSONStringer().object()
                .key("details").value(new JSONObject(json));
```

to

```
String billString = new JSONStringer().object()
                .key("details").value(new JSONObject(json)).endObject().toString();
```

The object syntax needs to be balanced -- there is a beginning and an ending.